# How to get access the div element referred to by a jquery dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a some javascript code whcih creates a dialog, that looks something like this:

```
 $( function () {
    $('.hoverList').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    hide: {
        effect: "fade",
        duration: 400
    },
    title: $(this).data("title"),
    modal: false
});};
```

In this case there may be multiple hoverlist class elements on the page.  The problem I am having is with this line in the above:

```
title: $(this).data("title")
```

On my pag, the div that contains my dialog looks like this:

```
<div class='hoverlist' data-title='My Dialog Title'>...</div>
```

When the javascript runs though, $(this) returned in the 'title:' key of the dialog refers tot he document itself, not to the element to which this dialog directive applies, so data("title") of the `<div>` element is not accessible here.

Note that there may several hoverlists on the same page, so I can't just select it by an id instead of a class without recreating the same code repeatedly.  Trying to figure out how I can construct the dialog with the title referred to in the data element of the `<div>` which I am turning into a dialog.  How might this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this, then you'll need to loop through the jQuery selector object, so that '$(this)' refers to the current node.

```
$( function () {

    $('.hoverList').each(function(){
        $(this).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            hide: {
                effect: "fade",
                duration: 400
            },
            title: $(this).data("title"),
            modal: false
        });
    });
});
```